# Appending a message to a buffer from a Vim script

Tags: scripting, vim

What's the best way to append the content of a string variable from a Vim script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If variable contains no newlines, then use

```
call append(line('$'), [variable])
```

, you can also do

```
call append(line('$'), split(variable, "\n"))
```

,

```
execute "normal! Go".variable
```

, or

```
execute "normal! Go\<C-r>\<C-r>=variable\<CR>"
```

Comment: The third way is `:$put=variable`

Comment: Great Thanks!! How do you insert it at the cursor position instead of a new line???

Comment: @Squirrl Replace `Go` with `i` in `:normal` calls. Using `append` will be tricky, you will basically need to acknowledge what `getline()`, `setline()`, `col('.')`, `line('.')` do and how to apply these to your case.

Answer (score 4):

You could also put the variable into a register like this:

```
let @a = variable

normal! G

execute "put a"
```

This works with or without carriage returns.

Comment: A quick note about this approach: if the user has something in this register, they'll lose it so it's better to avoid using a register in this case.